# How to create a script loop in Jenkins which continues or return success / error to pipeline based on json received by shell command?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using latest Jenkins in my Linux Box. I am trying to create a pipline with script block like below;

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('TestStage') { 
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "testfile.sh"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`testfile.sh` will return a json text like below;

```
{
    "Worker": [
        {
            "Status": "running"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `Status` can be either `running` or `success` or `failure`. If it is `running`, the code has to call `testfile.sh` again and check the status. If its `success`, pipeline has to continue to next step and if it is `failure`, pipeline has to terminate. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by creating a while loop that executes your script, reads the output and checks its value until a given timeout, when the status is no longer `running` you can check the result and fail the build according to the final status.
Something like:

```groovy
 pipeline {
     agent any
     stages {
         stage('TestStage') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {  // timeout for the 'running' period
                         def status = sh script: 'testfile.sh', returnStdout: true
                         while (status == 'running') {
                             sleep time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS'  // sleep between iterations
                             def output = sh script: 'testfile.sh', returnStdout: true
                             def dict = readJSON text: output
                             status = dict.Worker.Status
                         }
                     }
                     if(status == 'failure'){
                         error "Operation has ended with status 'failure'"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

You can find more info on the relevant steps: [sleep](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep), [timeout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit), [error](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal) and [readJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).